# Problem plotting secondary axis scale in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need some help in plotting the following data:

```
dat<- structure(list(V1 = c(1505.33, 1506.68, 1506.74, 1503.98, 1500.61, 
1497.75, 1498.56, 1499.99, 1499.67, 1494.91, 1488.28, 1485.49, 
1488.2, 1491.39, 1490.61, 1487.72, 1485.87, 1484.67, 1486.55, 
1492.35, 1502.85, 1509.32, 1511.05, 1510.59, 1510.97, 1507.79, 
1506.32, 1505.19, 1502.46, 1500.95, 1500.84, 1501.78, 1502.09, 
1501.19, 1501.34, 1502.5, 1502.76, 1500.87, 1496.96, 1492.09, 
1493.33), V2 = c(1.74527, 2.30103, 2.11998, 1.75153, 1.59016, 
2.02132, 2.00581, 2.48781, 2.73046, 2.42792, 2.63996, 2.94319, 
3.05106, 3.20972, 3.27096, 3.82272, 4.04051, 3.78384, 4.02734, 
5.29115, 6.08514, 4.43267, 3.20921, 2.42959, 2.01279, 2.18387, 
2.49999, 2.41115, 2.51137, 2.72333, 3.58609, 3.33229, 2.81728, 
2.78572, 3.10321, 3.44613, 3.02772, 2.38361, 1.86721, 2.15158, 
2.30715), date = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41), test = c(21.74527, 
22.30103, 22.11998, 21.75153, 21.59016, 22.02132, 22.00581, 22.48781, 
22.73046, 22.42792, 22.63996, 22.94319, 23.05106, 23.20972, 23.27096, 
23.82272, 24.04051, 23.78384, 24.02734, 25.29115, 26.08514, 24.43267, 
23.20921, 22.42959, 22.01279, 22.18387, 22.49999, 22.41115, 22.51137, 
22.72333, 23.58609, 23.33229, 22.81728, 22.78572, 23.10321, 23.44613, 
23.02772, 22.38361, 21.86721, 22.15158, 22.30715)), row.names = c(NA, 
-41L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have the following code for plotting.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafontdb)

dat<-as.data.frame(dat)
dat$date<-seq(1,41,by=1)

scaleFactor<-(max(dat$V1)/max(dat$V2))
print(scaleFactor)

p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=date))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y=V1),colour="blue",linetype="solid")  
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y=V2*scaleFactor,colour="black",linetype="longdash"))

p <- p + theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
    plot.margin = margin(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5, "cm"),
    panel.border=element_rect(colour="black",fill=NA,size=1),
    axis.line.x=element_line(colour="black"),
    axis.line.y=element_line(colour="black"),
    axis.text=element_text(size=15,colour="black",family="serif"),
    axis.title=element_text(size=15,colour="black",family="serif"),
    legend.position = "top", legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'white'))

p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(seq(1,41,4)),labels=c("-20","-16","-12","-8","-4","0","+4","+8","+12","+16","+20"),expand=c(0,0))
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./scaleFactor, name=expression(V["850hPa"](m~s^-1))))
p <- p + labs(x = "Lag (days)", y = expression(HGT["850hPa"](hPa)))
```

The output looks like this.

[image: Output]

**PROBLEM**

I cannot get the correct scale Factor to make a correct primary axis. The output image above is wrong. I want the primary axis (left y axis) to have values between 1480 and 1520 and the secondary axis (right axis) to have values between 0 and 7.

I will really appreciate any help on how I can plot this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scale according to the range of both variables and remember to add on the minimum value of V1 to V2. Here's a full reprex with the supplied `dat`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafontdb)

dat$date <- seq(1, 41, by = 1)

scaleFactor <- diff(range(dat$V1)) / diff(range(dat$V2))

p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=date)) +
       geom_line(aes(y = V1), colour = "blue", linetype = "solid")  + 
       geom_line(aes(y = V2 * scaleFactor + min(V1)), linetype = "longdash") +
       scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(1, 41, 4)), expand = c(0, 0),
                          labels = c("-20", "-16", "-12", "-8", "-4", "0",
                                     "+4", "+8", "+12", "+16", "+20")) +
       scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(. - min(dat$V1)) / scaleFactor, 
                                     name = expression(V["850hPa"](m~s^-1)))) +
       labs(x = "Lag (days)", y = expression(HGT["850hPa"](hPa))) +
       theme_classic() +
       theme(plot.margin     = margin(0.5, 0.5, 0.5 ,0.5, "cm"),
             panel.border    = element_rect(size = 1, fill = NA),
             axis.text       = element_text(size = 15, ,family = "serif"),
             axis.title      = element_text(size = 15, family = "serif"),
             legend.position = "top", 
             legend.key      = element_rect(fill = 'white'))
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>